# Сколько памяти использует видеокарта для обычного рендеринга окон

Tags: память, render, видеокарта

Правильно ли я посчитал?

Расширение `1920 * 1080`, а это `2073600` пикселей. На каждый пиксель уходит по 4 байта и того всего для целого `front-buffer` нужно около `8294400` байт, а это где-то грубо говорят 8 мегабайт. Учитывая, что `front-buffer` и `back-buffer`, каждый цикл обновляются, получается, что на обычную обрисовку уходит около 16 мегабайт видеопамяти? Или сюда нужно еще учесть операции с выбором и определением цвета и сказать приблизительно из-за этого количество памяти не так просто?